# How to view all variables associated with a plugin in vim

Tags: vim

Is there a way to do something like this in vim?

```
:echom g:tagbar*
```

Basically, I'd like to get a listing of all the `tagbar` variables and what they are set to (without having to enter each of them individually)

Comment: probably not what you're looking for, but you could `:echom g:tagbar` and then tab-complete your way through everything.  Should at least help you identify them.

Comment: How about `:echo filter(copy(g:), 'v:key =~ "tagbar"')` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
for v in split(execute(":let"), '\n')
  if v =~? '^tagbar_.*'
    echo v
  endif
endfor
```

Displays variables starting with `tagbar_` and their values

Answer (score 0):

`g:` is a predefined Dictionary of all global variables. You can do with it whatever you want.

```
:put =string(filter(copy(g:), {k, _ -> k =~? '^tagbar'}))
```